# Consecutive event handlers cause memory leak

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks, eventhandler

I am writing a Winform app have multiple event handlers, which run consecutively. My app crashes after 1-2 days and show 'Run out of memory exception'. I think event handlers caused this issues

My code below

-----Main form------

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Scanner _scanner; // class handle tasks and provide data to events
    public Form1() 
    {
        _scanner= new Scanner ();
        _scanner.Scan_STATUS += _scanner_SCAN_STATUS;
        _scanner.FAIL_COUNT += _scanner_FAIL_COUNT;
    }
    
    private void _scanner_SCAN_STATUS(object sender, Models.Event_Models.ScanStatusEventArg e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            lblStatus.Text = e.Status;
        }));
    }
    
    private void _scanner_FAIL_COUNT(object sender, Models.Event_Models.FailureCountArg e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            lblFailedCount.Text = e.FAIL_COUNT.ToString();
        }));
    }
    
    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            _Scanner.StartScan(settings);
        })
        { IsBackground = true }.Start();
    }
}
```

----- Scanner class do jobs-----

```
public class Scanner
{
    //Event
    public event EventHandler<FailureCountArg> FAIL_COUNT;
    protected virtual void On_FAIL_COUNT(FailureCountArg e)
    {
        FAIL_COUNT?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
    
    public event EventHandler<ScanStatusEventArg > SCAN_STATUS;
    protected virtual void On_SCAN_STATUS(ScanStatusEventArg e)
    {
        SCAN_STATUS?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
    
    private int _failure_count =0;
    // Main method
    public void StartScan(Setting settings) 
    {
        _failure_count =0;
        Parallel.ForEach(settings.ListItem, (item, state) =>
        {
            foreach (var pharse in settings.pharseList)
            {
                //Every item in parallel will check with pharse list whether it match condition or not 
                //Example: there 20000 item in parallel and 20000 pharse, so total check case: 400 millions
                //1 hour pass 400k cases , total 1000 hours to complete 20000 items with 20000 cases
                //and Status and fail_count will change value for every item in each case
                
                //Process item here then give feedback to status & value of _failure_count 
                //then display on winform label
                
                //Status will update for every item below in every case
                On_SCAN_STATUS(new ScanStatusEventArg ()
                {
                    Status = $"Data A processing...."
                });
                
                //If item not match condition , _failure_count increases value
                Interlocked.Increment(ref _failure_count);
                On_FAIL_COUNT(new FailureCountArg()
                {
                    FAIL_COUNT = _failure_count
                });
            }   
        });
    }
}
```

I have researched for online solutions however I might apply wrong way and exception still occurred, Please help me revise code resolve this memory leak. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I don't see the cause of the OOM problem in the code you've posted. What makes you believe the event handlers are the problem?

Comment: How is Form1 used? Opened and closed multiple times or just once? What memory profiling have you done? If you open Task Manager, go to Details and show the Handles, GDI Objects, User Objects and general memory usage, after a while, what increments most? -- What are you processing in parallel? The interlocked increment, in your code, is not clear in what cases increments the counter and what happens when a failure occurs. Do you need to dispose of stuff and you don't (e.g., clear collections without disposing of their disposable content)?

Comment: It's also not clear what calls `StartScan()` and when it's called.

Comment: I have revise codes, kindly check again

Comment: @C.Evenhuis because I read some articles about memory leak at events, events hold reference of task at right side +=, and not release for GC collect. My app can run until 1 week or longer to process all items in parallel list item, so I guess memory leak from events

Comment: @Jimi, Form1 keep opening and not closing, I did not know memory profiling, I observer task manager, memory goes up by time, I also did research articles about memory leaks, and events one of  the problem. Because my event will raise by every seconds for status and failure item count, so I guess events caused memory leak.

Comment: @Jimi, Handles up and down between 13k-13k5, user object 1082, GDI object between 100-104. A list of item process in parallel, when item not match the condition, failure_count increase.

Comment: When I comment event handles code, and let it run a day memory around 200-300mb, and with event handler after 15 hours, memory goes up to 1500 mb

Comment: Is this your real code? There's nothing here that suggests that memory usage could increase for a specific reason. It looks like you subscribe to the events just once. Do you have something in the UI that reacts to the what the event handlers return, besides a couple of Labels that change text? You have a load of open Handles there and almost no GDI objects used (just what's needed to maintain the UI). Do you have, e.g. - as mentioned - collections of Controls (or other disposable objects) that you just clear when some condition changes? The User objects count is also high.

Comment: Possibly, post a description of what this application is used for and what tasks are actually performed during its life-time. Also, what kind of objects you're handling (e.g., what is `settings.ListItem`)

Comment: @Jimi, yes my real code but not all the code, I just write the main code because other codes in using block may not affect.

Comment: @Jimi I have edited code and write more comments, please check!

Comment: Only label of 'fail_count' and 'status' change the most, other controls almost no changes.

Comment: @J.Tran the event handler causes a leak if you want to garbage collect `Form1`, but another object (or static) has a reference to its `Scanner` instance. Your code only shows a reference to `Scanner` from `Form1`, so that shouldn't be the problem.